# How to connect remotely to a Raspberry PI Zero

Tags: networking, ssh, pi-zero

I would like to setup my RPiZero to be connected to the LAN (wired) and be able to remotely connect from my Windows Desktop machine to it.

I need to know if the IP is dynamically set and how can I determine its IP address without needing to hook it up to a monitor.

Comment: Google is a useful tool.

Comment: If this was already answered (at least partially), you can vote to close my question and a link to the duplicate will be provided. I did search on Google before posting but did not find anything relevant to my issue.

Comment: Note *"Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once."*  Also note that if you cannot find the answer to all the distinct questions in this post by searching here or more broadly online then either your internet connection is broken or you are very bad at searching for information.

Comment: ok, I narrowed the question down

Comment: If it's your own network, you can log into your router and see if any DHCP leases are assigned to it.  Otherwise, you'll need to scan you network for it.  You're better off setting up a static DHCP reservation.  I'm sure Linux can technically be set to a static IP, but the last time I looked for directions, I was met with Linux-rage and directions/tutorials that did not get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your Pi + PC are on the same LAN?
I think you can determine easily the IP address of the PI launching a command arp -a
it will give you the list of the connected device on the LAN. you can filter the answer with the MAC address to keep only the PI IP
regards
CM